# .NET MVC5 Attribute Routing Optional Prefix

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

Trying to implement an optional routing prefix and running into some issues. Here is my route definition:

```
[RoutePrefix("{tenant:range(10,12)?}")]
[Route("{action=Index}")]
public class HomeController : Controller {
```

Routes are:

```
{tenant}/Index
{tenant}/Search
```

Loading the site with a tenant works fine, such as:
https://localhost:44300/10/

Using @Url.Action("Search", "Home") generates a correct link to the Search Action.

Without tenant, the site loads:
https://localhost:44300/

But I am unable to load the "non-default" action such as "Search", returns a 404. Also, the Url Helper generates a link such as: https://search

The range condition is temporary. I will have to further develop a custom constraint to actually verify the value.